# How to add Order total amount in words in woocommerce checkout, and email invoice

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Example: Total amount in words: **104.99 One hundred four and ninety-nine only**. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5yTz.jpg)

I will be displayed on my woocommerce checkout and in my woocommerce Email generated invoice.

Thank you

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show [what you have tried so far to solve your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are not a free coding platform, this is just a little approach. Goes into your `functions.php` file of your child theme. Tested and works. You still need to add the string translation for `total in words` and maybe a language check for the formatter output language.

```
/**
 * Add cart totals in words to checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total_action' );
function woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total_action() {
    $cart_totals      = WC()->cart->get_totals();
    $number_formatter = new NumberFormatter( "en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT );
    ?>
    <tr class="order-total-text">
        <th>total in words</th>
        <td><?= $number_formatter->format( $cart_totals['total'] ) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total_action' );
function woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total_action() {
   $number = WC()->cart->get_totals();
   $no = floor($number);
   $point = round($number - $no, 2) * 100;
   $hundred = null;
   $digits_1 = strlen($no);
   $i = 0;
   $str = array();
   $words = array('0' => '', '1' => 'one', '2' => 'two',
    '3' => 'three', '4' => 'four', '5' => 'five', '6' => 'six',
    '7' => 'seven', '8' => 'eight', '9' => 'nine',
    '10' => 'ten', '11' => 'eleven', '12' => 'twelve',
    '13' => 'thirteen', '14' => 'fourteen',
    '15' => 'fifteen', '16' => 'sixteen', '17' => 'seventeen',
    '18' => 'eighteen', '19' =>'nineteen', '20' => 'twenty',
    '30' => 'thirty', '40' => 'forty', '50' => 'fifty',
    '60' => 'sixty', '70' => 'seventy',
    '80' => 'eighty', '90' => 'ninety');
   $digits = array('', 'hundred', 'thousand', 'lakh', 'crore');
   while ($i < $digits_1) {
     $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
     $number = floor($no % $divider);
     $no = floor($no / $divider);
     $i += ($divider == 10) ? 1 : 2;
     if ($number) {
        $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
        $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
        $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number] .
            " " . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred
            :
            $words[floor($number / 10) * 10]
            . " " . $words[$number % 10] . " "
            . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred;
     } else $str[] = null;
  }
  $str = array_reverse($str);
  $result = implode('', $str);
  $points = ($point) ?
    "." . $words[$point / 10] . " " . 
          $words[$point = $point % 10] : ''
    ?>
    <tr class="order-total-text">
        <th>Total amounts in word</th>
        <td><?= $result . "Rupees  " . $points . " Paise"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```